# How do I create sticky header notification for promotions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a sticky notification that can be closed if the user wants to close.

I've so far achieved this:

```css
.top-head {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height:50px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <div class="top-head fixed-top">
        <span>Get $5 off when you spend $10. Enter FIVEOFF at checkout.</span>
        <span class="float-right">x</span>
        </div>
    <div class="header">
    Logo
    </div>
```

UPDATE: I have also added the header so that the issue can be further addressed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way.

for example:

```js
$(document).click('.top-head float-right', function() {
  $(".top-head > span").addClass('remove');
});
```

```css
.top-head {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.top-head span.remove {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="top-head fixed-top">
<span>Get $5 off when you spend $10. Enter FIVEOFF at checkout.</span>
<span class="float-right">x</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to remove the whole div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boostrap [alerts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/) plus a button containing the close icon:

```css
#tophead {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  background: #FFFFFF;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="tophead" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <span>Get $5 off when you spend $10. Enter FIVEOFF at checkout.</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Or, you can add a click event handler to your span:

```js
$('div.top-head.fixed-top span.float-right').on('click', function(e) {
    //$(this).closest('div.top-head.fixed-top').hide();
    // or, if you need to remove it
    $(this).closest('div.top-head.fixed-top').remove();
});
```

```css
.top-head {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="top-head fixed-top">
    <span>Get $5 off when you spend $10. Enter FIVEOFF at checkout.</span>
    <span class="float-right">x</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion but I'm looking to use Sticky div. Because I have Sticky header. So it will come something like this: https://prnt.sc/ox9kje

Comment: Thank you for your event handler. Can you review my updated code? What happens is the div you have created is hidden behind the header. Is there any solution to bring it above it? https://prnt.sc/ox9uo7